# Database.Logger.Level Enum Values Not Accessible in Version 11.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, logging, firebase-realtime-database

**Update 30 June:**

This problem is corrected in version 11.0.2.

---

Prior to Firebase version 11.0.0, the enum values of [Database.Logger.Level](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Logger.Level) were directly accessible.  An example that compiles with 10.2.6 is:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

That statement does not compile using version 11.0.0.  A workaround is to use `valueOf()`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.valueOf("DEBUG"));
```

In 11.0.0, the decompiled .class file for `Database.Logger` is:

```
public interface Logger {
    public static enum Level {
        zzcbX,
        zzcbY,
        zzcbZ,
        zzcca,
        zzccb;

        private Level() {
        }
    }
}
```

In 10.2.6, it's:

```
public interface Logger {
    public static enum Level {
        DEBUG,
        INFO,
        WARN,
        ERROR,
        NONE;

        private Level() {
        }
    }
}
```

Is use of `valueOf()` the appropriate workaround until the enum values are accessible again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is a known bug in version 11.0.0 and 11.0.1 of the Android SDK. It should be fixed in version 11.0.2, which is due by early July.