# Firebase Database not working and no response

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert a new user record in to my Firebase database:

```
    databaseReference
            .child("users")
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
            .setValue(User.fromFirebaseUser(application.firebaseUser))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    startActivity(MainActivity.createIntent(SplashActivity.this));
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    showSnackbar(R.string.error_user_registration_failed);
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "complete");
                }
            });
```

But nothing happens. There is no messages from logcat and none of the listeners get hit.

My permissions are the default (must be authenticated) and I've made sure I am. A call to `firebaseUser.getUid()` just before the database call returns the current userId as expected.

I've triple checked all my dependencies and made sure my google-services.json file is up to date.

I've tried to enable debugging via `firebaseDatabase.setLogLevel()` but for some reason `Logger.Level` doesn't contain the enums (they're obfuscated?)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Workaround for `setLogLevel()` problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44468817/4815718

Comment: Sometimes play service in the background freezes and all the firebase system is offline, make sure play services is running ok. Might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After enabling debugging (thanks Bob Snyder) it gave me an error.

Essentially you need to enable the "Token Service API" in your [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/securetoken.googleapis.com/overview). I'm not sure why and how this relates to FirebaseDatabase, and I couldn't find any references to it throughout Google's docs, but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with reading the users data..

I changed the database rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

And it worked, but make sure you kill the app first after changing and publishing the new rules.

**Note:** these rules are only for testing and should never be saved for the published app

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have "firebase_url":  in google-services.json file in project_info": block. Some how in my case the URL option was not created.

**Note:** In the url option you have to give your firebase database link

Comment: This happens when you create a project and download google-services.json before creating a database. You cured my heartache. I didn't sleep for a night. Thanks.