# How to see Debug logging in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am  using firebase version 11.0.1

I try this code

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

but it doesn't work! syntax error.. I click on level class and this is what I see??? package com.google.firebase.database;

```
public interface Logger {
    public static enum Level {
        zzbYY,
        zzbYZ,
        zzbZa,
        zzbZb,
        zzbZc;

        private Level() {
        }
    }
}
```

Is deprecated? How to do it?

Comment: This is Firebase bug that will be fixed in the next release.  Workaround is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44468817/4815718.  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.valueOf("DEBUG"));`