# can not write to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can not write to database , database don't show updates

**Main class**

```
  var nam: EditText = findViewById(R.id.name)
            var ema: EditText = findViewById(R.id.email)
            var pho: EditText = findViewById(R.id.phone)
            var pas: EditText = findViewById(R.id.password)
            var confpass: EditText = findViewById(R.id.conf_password)
            val reg: Button = findViewById(R.id.submit_button)
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            reg.setOnClickListener {


                    writeUser(nam.text.toString(), ema.text.toString(), pho?.text.toString())
                }
```

**Function create user**

```
  private fun writeUser(name: String, email: String, phone: String) {
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val modelUser=User(name,email,null)
        database.child("users").child(name).setValue(modelUser).addOnCompleteListener {
            task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else{
                Log.d("writing", task.exception?.message)
            }
        }


    }
```

in log i have this info

> 02/12 14:18:30: Launching app $ adb shell am start -n
>   "com.example.sg772.foodorder/com.example.sg772.foodorder.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online Connected to
>   process 8788 on device Pixel_API_28 [emulator-5554] Capturing and
>   displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be
>   disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings
>   page. W/sg772.foodorde: JIT profile information will not be recorded:
>   profile file does not exits. I/chatty:
>   uid=10098(com.example.sg772.foodorder) identical 10 lines
>   W/sg772.foodorde: JIT profile information will not be recorded:
>   profile file does not exits. V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle
>   callback W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found. D/FirebaseApp:
>   com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping
>   initialization. I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization
>   successful I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   V/FA: Collection enabled
>       App package, google app id: com.example.sg772.foodorder, 1:980467406963:android:245f3c07814d7a09 I/FA: App measurement is
>   starting up, version: 14710 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb
>   shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>       To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.sg772.foodorder D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor
>   class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. I/FirebaseAuth:
>   [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
>       [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation V/FA: Connecting to remote service V/FA: Connection
>   attempt already in progress W/sg772.foodorde: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
>   (light greylist, reflection) W/sg772.foodorde: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light
>   greylist, reflection) D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline I/FA: Tag
>   Manager is not found and thus will not be used D/FA: Logging event
>   (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=3005354659345179733}] D/:
>   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xebdd9f80, tid
>   8817 I/ConfigStore:
>   android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
>   retrieved: 0
>       android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay
>   retrieved: 0 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose
>   config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext:
>   0xec004360: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2 V/FA: Connection attempt already in
>   progress V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress V/FA: Activity
>   resumed, time: 9035919 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec004360:
>   ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xec003920) I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec004360: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xec003920) I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1117ms; Flags=0,
>   IntendedVsync=9036091549283, Vsync=9036624882595,
>   OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0,
>   HandleInputStart=9036641897950, AnimationStart=9036642110860,
>   PerformTraversalsStart=9036642975280, DrawStart=9036650223070,
>   SyncQueued=9036662730370, SyncStart=9036667360980,
>   IssueDrawCommandsStart=9036739674550, SwapBuffers=9037130366220,
>   FrameCompleted=9037214105920, DequeueBufferDuration=71000,
>   QueueBufferDuration=1178000,  D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. V/FA: Processing queued up service
>   tasks: 4 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=796ms; Flags=0,
>   IntendedVsync=9036658942220, Vsync=9037242275530,
>   OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0,
>   HandleInputStart=9037253016620, AnimationStart=9037253130120,
>   PerformTraversalsStart=9037253753900, DrawStart=9037254539400,
>   SyncQueued=9037255108140, SyncStart=9037258003500,
>   IssueDrawCommandsStart=9037262367020, SwapBuffers=9037341124110,
>   FrameCompleted=9037458265820, DequeueBufferDuration=204000,
>   QueueBufferDuration=267000,  V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the
>   service

Comment: Is your Toast message displayed? If not, does `Log.d("writing", task.exception?.message)` print something?

Comment: no toast and no log message

Comment: Is your onSuccess method even triggered? Are you sure you have internet connection on your device?

Comment: internet on my device i works . On my emulator : oh ! i didnt think about it 
how can check if onSuccess is triggered ? so if there is no toast ot means that this method dont work ?

Comment: Enable firebase logging and check error again `FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Have you tried to see what `onFailure` returns? Please reponde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @HemantParmar how can do it ? i dont found this build in method

Comment: @androidev refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767654/how-to-see-debug-logging-in-firebase)

Comment: @AlexMamo 
thanks ! the problem is solved 
i suffered with this issue two ours but it was the reboot of emulator that is solution

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting."